# Choosing one value from partially duplicate rows

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to choose between two rows of data in order to get a total count of type.

```
Table - Evaluations
EvaluationID (link to minEval_ID and max_EvalID)
EstablishedDelays

Table - Outcome
min_EvalID
max_EvalID
EligTypeRecalc
```

This is what my current query is:

```
SELECT "NewEligType"=
COUNT (*),
SUM (CASE WHEN  a.EligTypeRecalc IN (1,4,5,7) Then 1 Else 0 END) 'Established Condition',
SUM (CASE WHEN  a.EligTypeRecalc=6 Then 1 Else 0 END) 'Established Delay & At-Risk',
SUM (CASE WHEN  a.EligTypeRecalc=2 and b.EstablishedDelays=1 Then 1 Else 0 END) 'Established Delay only: One Delay',
SUM (CASE WHEN  a.EligTypeRecalc=2 and b.EstablishedDelays=2 Then 1 Else 0 END) 'Established Delay only: Two Delays',
SUM (CASE WHEN  a.EligTypeRecalc=2 and b.EstablishedDelays>=3 Then 1 Else 0 END) 'Established Delay only: Three+ Delays',
SUM (CASE WHEN  a.EligTypeRecalc=8 Then 1 Else 0 END) 'Clinical Judgement'

from Outcome a
join Evaluations b
on a.max_EvalID=b.evaluationid and a.min_evalID=b.evaluationID
where a.EligTypeRecalc<>3
```

The problem I'm encountering is picking the correct Eval_ID to choose the correct number of delays and not count the other. The EstablishedDelays associated with max_EvalID is correct unless the EligTypeRecalc is 0, then it should count the delays associated with min_EvalID.

So far I've come up with this basic logic but I'm having a mind block on how to get it to the next step:

```
CASE WHEN EligTypeRecalc=max_EvalID
  THEN EstablishedDelays=max_EvalID
  ELSE EstablishedDelays=min_EvalID
```

Bonus points: I only have Read access to the database.

****What's the proper query syntax to use to select the row associated and exclude the other?**

Thanks for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code I used, its a little long:

```
WITH min_eval AS
(
SELECT
    a.DataMatch,
    a.max_EvalID,
    a.EligTypeRecalc,
    b.evaluationid,
    b.EstablishedDelays
FROM Outcomes a
JOIN Evaluations b
    ON a.min_EvalID=b.evaluationid
    WHERE a.EligTypeRecalc<>3
),
max_eval AS
(
SELECT
    a.DataMatch,
    a.max_EvalID,
    a.EligTypeRecalc,
    b.evaluationid,
    b.EstablishedDelays
FROM Outcomes a
JOIN Evaluations b
    ON a.max_EvalID=b.evaluationid
    WHERE a.EligTypeRecalc<>3
)
SELECT "NewEligType"=
    COUNT (*),
    SUM (CASE WHEN  a.EligTypeRecalc IN (1,4,5,7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Established Condition',
    SUM (CASE WHEN  a.EligTypeRecalc=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Established Delay & At-Risk',
    SUM (CASE WHEN  (a.EligTypeRecalc=2 AND a.EstablishedDelays=1) OR (a.EligTypeRecalc=2 AND a.EstablishedDelays=0 AND b.EligTypeRecalc=2 AND b.EstablishedDelays=1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Established Delay only: One Delay',
    SUM (CASE WHEN  (a.EligTypeRecalc=2 AND a.EstablishedDelays=2) OR (a.EligTypeRecalc=2 AND a.EstablishedDelays=0 AND b.EligTypeRecalc=2 AND b.EstablishedDelays=2)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Established Delay only: Two Delays',
    SUM (CASE WHEN  (a.EligTypeRecalc=2 AND a.EstablishedDelays>=3) OR (a.EligTypeRecalc=2 AND a.EstablishedDelays=0 AND b.EligTypeRecalc=2 AND b.EstablishedDelays>=3)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Established Delay only: Three+ Delays',
    SUM (CASE WHEN  a.EligTypeRecalc=8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'Clinical Judgement'

FROM max_eval a
JOIN min_eval b
    ON a.DataMatch=b.DataMatch
```

Answer (score 1):

You might try wrapping your summary of the Evaluations table into a CTE and then join that to the Outcome table.